# Does Opera Mini support Content-Encoding?

Tags: php, opera-mini

I am creating a wap portal, and wanted to know if Opera Mini supports gzip encoding?

However, does

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

automatically check if the browser supports gzip and sends the gzipped encoded content or do we need to check that manually ?

Comment: gzip encoding on mobile devices sounds like a battery killer.

Comment: Gzip compression doesn't harm the battery when using Opera Mini b/c the decompression is done on the Opera Mini servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got my answer, it support gzip, x-gzip, identity, deflate**

and for gzip

```
<?php
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) 
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
else
    ob_start();
?>
```